# Python Datalogger using redirection

Tags: python, linux, io-redirection

I have a python script (`main.py`), and I would like to save all the "print()s" into a file (`log.txt`). The simpliest way to do that is to redirect the output into the file when the script is called:

```
python3 main.py >> log.txt
```

The main problem is that the text I want to save is only stored when the script ends propperly. For example, if the script is running and I manually press Alt+F4, the datalogger works perfect. But if the PC is shutted down (voltage supply), nothing is stored.

How can I solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: The reason no output is stored is that, output from `print` function calls are buffered by python, and when the script does not finish, no output is flushed to the file. You could try `sys.stdout.flush()` after `print` in your script.